# HighlightColorIndex Incorrectly Displaying Color

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am writing a program in Excel to create some stickers in Word. I use the HighlightColorIndex and for whatever reason, it highlights my text black. No matter what color I choose, it is always black. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
Word.Application.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
Word.Application.Selection.Font.Bold = True
Word.Application.Selection.Font.Size = 10
Word.Application.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdClassicBlue
Word.Application.Selection.TypeText Text:="Job: " & ListBox1.List(x, 0) & cutlist
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Word Application Library?

Comment: You may benefit from adding `Option Explicit` as it will tell you if you are trying to use undeclared variables, like `wdClassicBlue`

Comment: I have the Word Object Lib and just tried adding the Explicit. Still appearing black, thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply that `wdClassicBlue` is not a valid value for `HighlightColorIndex`.

Your blue-ish options are:

- wdTurquoise
- wdBlue
- wdDarkBlue
- wdTeal

Comment: I wondered when I didn't see it in the enum docs.

Comment: @BigBen - It's an easy mistake to make because although it only takes a sub-set of `wdColorIndex` Intellisense lists all the values.

Comment: So I did end up changing to use `wdBlue` and it appears to be working now, but when i type in `HighlightColorIndex =` my list of color options appears and wdClassicBlue is on the list. Either way it is working now, just interesting is all. Thank you!